# Adding emphasis to a text editor?

Tags: python, text-editor, rich-text-editor

I'm going to make a simple text editor in python for fun. I have a general idea of how I'm going to do it. The only thing I'm having trouble understanding right now is how I will add the bold, italics, and underline options. How would I let the user italicize some text for example? Is there a python module for doing this? Or is it more on the GUI side?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's more on the GUI side. What graphical framework/module are you using to make your text editor?

Comment: Probably Glade, unless you have other suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are just starting with the GUI I think you should start from Tkinter first.
Here is an example to write text in some styles you are looking for.

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()

text2 = Text(root, height=20, width=50)


## create separate tags for separate fonts
text2.tag_configure('normal', font=('Arial', 20))
text2.tag_configure('italics', font=('Arial', 20,'italic'))
text2.tag_configure('bold', font=('Arial', 20,'bold'))
text2.tag_configure('underline', font=('Arial', 20,'underline'))
text2.tag_configure('all', font=('Arial', 20,'bold','italic','underline'))

##use the tags to print text in a particular font
text2.insert(END,'This text is Normal\n','normal' )
text2.insert(END,'This text is Bold\n', 'bold')
text2.insert(END, "this text is italics\n", 'italics')
text2.insert(END, "this text is underline\n", 'underline')
text2.insert(END, "this text is everything\n", 'all')
text2.pack(side=LEFT)

root.mainloop()
```

after knowing how Tkinter works you can create separate functions and then bind them to keys to select your own font like.

`(ctrl+b) for` **BOLD**
`(ctrl+i) for` *italics*
`(ctrl+u) for` underline

Comment: The poster did say he was using Glade to make the GUI.

Comment: @icedtrees OP mentioned it in comment with the word `probably`..
I am just showing him a way to this in python.

Comment: @Ignacio in this example you can delete and rewrite text which I think is a major part of text editor...
If I am not wrong you might be asking for some other functions that a text editor provides so that's upto the OP to find out...
I will delete the `EDITOR` part from my answer btw thanks

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this out soon and see how it works